# Undefined variable $new_width, php image cropping

Tags: php, mysql

```
class Image 
{

    public function generate_filename($length)
    {
        $array = array(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'Ö');
        $text = "";
 
        for($x = 0; $x < $length; $x++)
        {
        $random = rand(0,18);
        $text .= $array[$random];
        }
        return $text = "";
    }
public function crop_image($original_file_name,$cropped_file_name,$max_width,$max_height)
 {
    if(file_exists($original_file_name))
        {
               $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($original_file_name);

               $original_width = imagesx($original_image);
               $original_height = imagesy($original_image);
               if($original_height > $original_width)
               {
                         //reduce the width so that it is equal to the max width
                         $ratio = $max_width / $original_width;

                         $new_width = $max_width; 
                         $new_height = $original_height * $ratio;
               }else 
               {
                $ratio = $max_height / $original_height;

                $new_height = $max_height; 
                $new_width = $original_width * $ratio;
               }
        }
        
        if($max_width != $max_height)
        {
            if($max_height > $max_width)
            {
                if($max_height > $new_height)
                {
                    $adjustment = ($max_height / $new_height);
                }else 
                {
                    $adjustment = ($new_height / $max_height);
                }

                $new_width = $new_width * $adjustment;
                $new_height = $new_height * $adjustment;
            }else 
            {
                if($max_width > $new_width)
                {
                    $adjustment = ($max_width / $new_width);
                }else 
                {
                    $adjustment = ($new_width / $max_width);
                }

                $new_width = $new_width * $adjustment;
                $new_height = $new_height * $adjustment;

            }
        }

        $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);
//save memory
        imagedestroy($original_image);
        if ($max_width != $max_height)
        {
            if($max_width > $max_height)
            {
                $diff = ($new_height - $max_height);
                if($diff < 0) {
                $diff = $diff * -1;
                }
                $y = round($diff / 2);
                $x = 0;
            }else 
            {
                $diff = ($new_width - $max_height);
                if($diff < 0) {
                    $diff = $diff * -1;
                    }
                $x = round($diff / 2);
                $y = 0;
            }
        }else 
          {

        if($new_height > $new_width)
        {
            $diff = ($new_height - $new_width);
            $y = round($diff / 2);
            $x = 0;
        }else 
        {
            $diff = ($new_width - $new_height);
            $x = round($diff / 2);
            $y = 0;
        }
    }

        $new_cropped_image = imagecreatetruecolor($max_width, $max_height);
        imagecopyresampled($new_cropped_image, $new_image, 0, 0, $x, $y, $max_width, $max_height, $max_width, $max_height);

        imagedestroy($new_image);

        imagejpeg($new_image,$cropped_file_name, 90);
        imagedestroy($new_cropped_image);
    }
}
```

So this is just a basic function that is supposed to crop the image a user uploads for them, the "math" or logic behind the size reduction is taken from some random youtube video so its really nothing sophisticated but is supposed to just be a sort of demo. Watched it over and over again mimicking it and tried other ways but still $new_width is undefined.

Comment: You're only defining `new_width` and `new_height` if `$max_width != $max_height` or if the file exists.. If they match and the file doesn't exist, those variables aren't defined.

Comment: Thats true thank you. How would you go about making this more functional ?

Comment: I would suggest defining those two variables at the top of the function. You can assign the max values to those variables so they have a default value.

Comment: So im trying to declare new_height and new_width at the start but i cant figure out how to declare them as numerical or like pixel values / asigning a value to the variable.

Comment: At the top of the script, just do `$new_height = $max_height; $new_width = $max_width;`